# Eclipse Mars crashes when attempting to add GlassFish 4 Server

Tags: glassfish-4, linux-mint, eclipse-mars

When I am trying to add a new GlassFish Server *(Servers -> New -> Server -> GlassFish 4)* Eclipse Mars just crashes (without any errors).
Reinstallation of IDE and GlassFish not helped.
Maybe someone faced such problem? Help me please.
I am using Linux Mint 17.3, Eclipse Mars 4.5.1, GlassFish 4.1.1, JDK 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug in Eclipse. I am also encountering it in `Eclipse Neon`.
Please see [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=479056).

Comment: is there a workaround for this? facing the same issue